# How to interpret tensorboard histograms in CNN

Tags: keras, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard to monitor the training of my CNN, and each time I ignore the histograms because I don't understand what tensorboard is trying to show me or what I should interpret from it. Is there any insight that I can use that can help me to improve my model in any way, or is it just... a visualisation that looks cool?

[image: Histograms sample]